# Advantage and Disadvantage of J2ME?

Tags: java-me

I would like a list of advantages/disadvantages of J2ME, mainly MIDP. I figured that this would be the best place to ask since there seems to be a wealth of knowledge in this forum.
Currently I have the following advantages in J2ME.,

```
* Rich Clients
* Offline use
* Consistency of applications across platforms
* Reuse of existing code base
```

I don't really have a list of disadvantages although I am sure that there are plenty. Any views on either advantages/disadvantages[ie., Limitations of J2ME] would be welcome.

Thanks in advance,
Tilsan the Fighter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noone of them. Main disadvantage is paranoidal security model. For instance [read here](http://javablog.co.uk/2007/08/09/how-midlet-signing-is-killing-j2me/).

Answer (score 0):

We cannot able to access the database directly.For database we should connect to intermediate.From that intermediate we should access the database.From that intermediate the result is return the j2me.Here the intermediate is any one of the following such as servlet,etc.

Answer (score 0):

As barmaley said and the link given. LWUIT allows you to create really nice J2ME apps, but really, J2ME is in it's death throws. Unless you have a specific requirement to use J2ME now, you'd be better off targeting Android.