# Where can I find java.util.Properties file?

Tags: java, java-me

I am facing this error when I am trying to call database connection from MIDlet class. I have created a class file for JDBC connection and created an object for that class in MIDlet class. I trying to call that JDBC connection method in the startApp() method of MIDlet, but I am facing the following error.

> cannot access java.util.Properties
>   class file for java.util.Properties not found
>
> Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/j2me","root","mysql");
>   1 error

in the code

```
import java.sql.*;
public class JDBCprogram {
    public void runJDBC() {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/j2me","root","mysql");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sqlquery = "select * from employee";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlquery);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the syntax here, where the user and password are placed in the connection string?: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Comment: JavaME contains only a subset of java.util.*. I don't think the java.util.Properties is available.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something with your runtime class path is wrong, that could be a simple answer, unless the error is misleading.

Comment: What I have to include then?

Comment: just realised you're in a micro edition of the full JVM, so you will have limitations applied to the standard Java libraries. My immediate thought is to not connect straight to the database from this app, but rather call a server side app (using J2SE) that where you'll implement the JDBC call to the database. I saw such a thing mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986250/advantage-and-disadvantage-of-j2me  as I looked for "J2ME limitations".

Comment: Well it's a helpful link for me but my task is to connect to the database without servlet. Is there any possibility?

Comment: In order to try this, you can try to add additional jars to the MIDlet application deployable. I haven't built MIDlets myself, but I can imagine there are also security reasons and performance reasons why certain things aren't available by default. I'd search for proof that people have done it, based on the little I've seen so far about this. I'm assuming you might have done that, and the servlet seems nearer. I take this option is challenging regarding additional hosting issues, but it's a more straightforward and secure model in my view.

Comment: I've tried many ways to rectify that error but in vain. If you find any solution please share here. I've also added different jar files like mysql connector and jdbc api.

Comment: Developers usually use a server-side scripting in the middle, simply because it's easy. It doesn't have to be a Servlet. You can easily use e.g. PHP instead.